# C# Json.net Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-core-mvc, httpclient

I am getting the above error while trying to get the Json format from a url.

```
  public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("externalId")]
    public int ExternalId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("barcode")]
    public int Barcode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("retailPrice")]
    public double RetailPrice { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("wholesalePrice")]
    public double WholesalePrice { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("discount")]
    public double Discount { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    public List<Product> GetProducts { get; set; }
}
```

and in my controller I have:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        string url = "https://cloudonapi.oncloud.gr/s1services/JS/updateItems/cloudOnTest";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string jsonResponse = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Products>(jsonResponse);

        return View(list);

    }
```

I keep getting *the Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.* error

Comment: Have you inspected the `jsonResponse` string to see what it is?

Comment: @JamesGould Yes it's a string, formatted wrong, like: "\u001f‹\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0µ•έnΪ0\u0014Η_ε(WT¥Αv0\u001f½\vΑ΄Ρ\f±’\u008c±M»Θ \u0090\u0018L@5¤―Τwh¥ξ««iκϋμ8”¬$™ΤNτ*Ρ±}\u008e\u007fηγοScq2\u001cΖ‹…qΈ\u009c\u009fΔe0FΡ22\u000eί\u009e\u001aρj\u0019Ο§ΡΔ\u001d\u0019p\b†Ε\u001aΌV5ΚΖp6\u00\0" etc..

Comment: well there you have it, you need to request the data with the right encoding, and you need to adjust your Products Object to match the json structure

Comment: I think you also need to change the `Products` to `public class Products {
 public bool success { get; set; }
 public List<Product> data { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So. `\u001f` means you received the byte `1F`. `‹` is in the range of [extended ASCII](https://www.garykessler.net/library/ascii.html) with encoding `8B`. `\b` is the ASCII backspace character with encoding `08`.

`1F 8B` is the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) for GZIP (and the `08` is the [compression method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip): DEFLATE).

So, the server's one of the broken ones which gives you back a gzip-compressed response, even though you didn't say you could accept gzip-compressed responses.

You can tell `HttpClient` to automatically decompress gzip-compressed responses:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};
using var client = new HttpClient(handler));

var httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
// ...
```